# Apache Camel SOAP/CXF request to Server (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, soap, apache-camel, wsdl, camel-cxf

I am trying to make requests to dedicated WSDL server with the help of Apache Camel CXF.

I have the WSDL URL:
http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/tempconverter?wsdl

I've made the Java classes of WSDL using the cxf-codegen-plugin:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/tempconverter.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <packagenames>
                                        <packagename>office.planet.integrations.merlion</packagename>
                                    </packagenames>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have the following Camel route:

```java
@Component
public class MerlionRoute
      extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:celsius-to-fahrenheit")
              .process(exchange -> {
                  System.out.println("HELLO!!!!!");
                  CelsiusToFahrenheitRequest c = new CelsiusToFahrenheitRequest();
                  c.setTemperatureInCelsius(Double.valueOf(exchange.getIn().getHeader("num").toString()));
                  exchange.getIn().setBody(c);
              })
              .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("CelsiusToFahrenheit"))
              .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("{{endpoint.namespace}}"))
              .to("cxf:bean:cxfConvertTemp")
              .process(exchange -> {
                  System.out.println("WE ARE HERE");
                  MessageContentsList response = (MessageContentsList) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                  CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse r = (CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse) response.get(0);
                  exchange.getIn().setBody("Temp in Farenheit: "+r.getTemperatureInFahrenheit());
                  System.out.println(r.getTemperatureInFahrenheit());
              })
              .end();
    }
}
```

The Bean class of the EndPoint:

```java
@Configuration
public class CxfBeans {
    @Value("${endpoint.wsdl}")
    private String SOAP_URL;
    
    @Bean(name = "cxfConvertTemp")
    public CxfEndpoint buildCxfEndpoint() {
        CxfEndpoint cxf = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxf.setAddress(SOAP_URL);
        cxf.setServiceClass(TempConverterEndpoint.class);
        cxf.setWsdlURL(SOAP_URL);
        return cxf;
    }
}
```

And the WSDL endpoint:

```java
endpoint.wsdl=http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/tempconverter?wsdl
endpoint.namespace=http://learnwebservices.com/services/tempconverter
```

When I am launching the project, my route starts, but nothing happens.
Only this I can see:

```java
2022-03-31 18:41:44.933  INFO 44313 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://learnwebservices.com/services/tempconverter}TempConverterEndpointService from WSDL: http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/tempconverter?wsdl
```

How shall I request the data from WSDL server within the Camel CXF? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your route needs to be triggered. As it stands, nothing calls your from endpoint `"direct:celsius-to-fahrenheit"`, and thus indeed, nothing happens.

Assuming you want this route to be triggered only once, you could define your from endpoint as `"timer://celsius-to-fahrenheit?repeatCount=1"`.

See [Camel Timer component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html).

Comment: You could also write a unit test that calls the route, but as you stated it is indeed currently never triggered.